# Fit a SVG curve to a polynomial

Tags: javascript, graphics, svg

Assuming I have functions like x² or 2x + 3x² how does one go about creating a SVG path that fits these functions ?.

From my limited understanding of **SVG** and **Bezier** curves I believe I am looking 
for is a simple technique to construct the bezier control points that will ensure that the resulting graph fits the given function. You can safely assume (if you have not already guessed so) that I am a newbie in graphics programming. I know frameworks like [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) can perform this type of interpolation but I am looking more for a explanation on how to do it by hand using **SVG** and **JavaScript**.

**EDIT:** A exact fit is not a strict requirement, but the resulting graph has to be reasonably accurate (for teaching purposes).

Comment: I'm not sure if you can *exactly* describe a polynomial with a bezier curve of the same degree.

Comment: @CodeInChaos great feedback, out of curiosity how do people then graph a polynomial with SVG ?, I have seen it done but unsure about how people go from function to graph. Exact fit is not a strict requirement, although of cause the graph has to be reasonably accurate.

Comment: I assume they graph it just like any other function: calculate the function value at many points along the curve (1000 or so) and then fit a function through it. It the simplest case with lines, but it'll certainly look better with higher degree bézier curves, but I don't remember a convenient way to calculate control points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
```

SVG provides Bézier curves of orders 2 and 3, which should be good enough for quadratic and cubic polynomials.

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="20cm" height="20cm" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
    .axis { fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 3; }
    .tick { fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1; }
    .fun1 { fill: none; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 2; }
    .fun2 { fill: none; stroke: red; stroke-width: 2; }
  ]]></style>
  <polyline class="axis" points="0,500 1000,500" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="0,490 0,510" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="100,490 100,510" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="200,490 200,510" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="300,490 300,510" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="400,490 400,510" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="600,490 600,510" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="700,490 700,510" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="800,490 800,510" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="900,490 900,510" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="1000,490 1000,510" />
  <polyline class="axis" points="500,0 500,1000" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="490,0 510,0" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="490,100 510,100" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="490,200 510,200" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="490,300 510,300" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="490,400 510,400" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="490,600 510,600" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="490,700 510,700" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="490,800 510,800" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="490,900 510,900" />
  <polyline class="tick" points="490,1000 510,1000" />
```

Take y = x² - 4, with endpoints (-3, 5) and (3, 5); the tangents are y = -6x - 13 and y = 6x - 13.  Place the one `Q` control point on both tangents, at (0, -13).  This should work easily for any quadratic.

```
  <path class="fun1" d="M200,0 Q500,1800 800,0" />
```

Cubics are a bit tricker.  With y = (x³ - 9x) / 16 from (-5, -5) to (5, 5), the tangents are y = (33x + 125) / 8 and y = (33x - 125) / 8.  Seeing that the curve must pass through (0, 0) with slope -9/16, it's a simple calculation to find `C` control points (-5/3, 35/4) and (5/3, 35/4).  It's probably not doable by hand most of the time but I think this approach should be numerically doable for any other cubic — two variables for how far along each tangent the control points lie, and two constraints forcing a particular point and direction.

```
  <path class="fun2" d="M0,1000 C333,-375 667,1375 1000,0" />
```

([Animated Bézier Curves](http://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/) was very helpful when I was working these out.)

```
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic answer. Am I correct in observing that there is no generalization to higher order polynomials (other than stitching together a ton of small straight lines ?).

Comment: @LarsTackmann, if SVG had order-4 Béziers, I would expect to be able to draw quartic polynomials, and so on.  But that would get complex quickly.  Using Bézier splines (should be able to match the first and second derivatives) would look nicer than line segments, but either way, it wouldn't be exact.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for formulas, but I found responses.

For the cubic Bézier curve you need 4 points : P0 Pc0 Pc1 P1

```
We consider x0 < x1, f(x) = ax³ + bx² + cx + d and f'(x) = 3ax² + 2bx + c.
```

So for the formulas we have :

[Equations form A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZXtl.png) or (it's equivalent) [Equations form B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxdR8.png)

I hope this will be helpful for someone else.